# Visual Studio Windows Universal error ocurred retrieving package metadata

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

If I want to create a new Windows Universal app I get an error message:

The error message:

> "An error ocurred while retrieving package metadata for
>   'System.Collections.Immutable.1.1.37' from source
>   Path.nuget\packages.

[image]

I tried reinstalling visual studio and repairing it.
How can i fix the error.
After I click ok:
I get several errors: 
The namespace name can not be found in the namespace System.

Information about pc:
Windows 10 Education Version, Hyper V activated.
**It worked in an earlier version of visual studio!**

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling the System.Collections.Immutable nuget?  What output do you get in the `Package Manager` output window when you do this?

Comment: @KoryGill How do i reinstall that? I reinstalled whole visual studio.... Where to get the output of the packet manager?

Comment: 1) Project, Manage NuGet Packages. 2) View, Output, Show output from dropdown in Output window.

Comment: @KoryGill If i click at manage nuGet Packages it says there are elements which can be found

Comment: Can you update your question with additional information, including relevant screen shots where applicable that demonstrate the problem? Perhaps that will help readers of the question help find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download System.Collections.Immutable (1.1.36) from nuget.org
2. The file downloaded is a zip file with a .nupkg extension, rename the file to .zip
3. Open the zip file, go to the lib folder and into a folder called portable-net45%2Bwin8%2Bwp8%2Bwpa81
4. Copy the System.Collection.Immutable.dll file into one of the Atmel Studio load folders
5. using '\Extensions\Application', which might be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Extensions\Application' on your machine

This should make it work.

Comment: I will give that a try

Comment: @S A I can't find the path in step 5 :( My Path to nuget packages is "C:\Users\matthias\.nuget\packages" The folder Atmel doesn't exist in my Program Files(x86) folder...

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
I deleted the .nuget folder in path: Users\MyName.nuget and closed visual studio, after reopening and creating a new windows universal project it got fixed. The folder was recreated automatically